# I need help solving a differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Can someone please help me solve this differential equation.

$\frac{dy}{dx} =x^2 + y^2$.

Comment: I don't think that has a closed form.

Comment: Are you sure that it isn't?

Comment: There is a solution which involves Bessel functions and it is quite complex. Are you sure about the equation ?

Comment: Yes I am sure..

Comment: [Possibly related and of interest?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation)

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y'(x)%3Dy%5E2%2Bx%5E2

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=x^2+y^2$$
This is a Ricati ODE. In the general case, the usual method to solve it is a change of function :
$$y(x)=-\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}\qquad\to\qquad f''+x^2f=0$$
The new ODE is a particular case of parabolic cylinder ODE which solutions are linear combinations of the parabolic cylinder functions : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ParabolicCylinderDifferentialEquation.html

In this particular cases, the ODE can be transformed to an ODE of Bessel kind which general solution is :
$$f(x)=c_1\sqrt{x}\:J_{1/4}\left(\frac{1}{2}x^2\right)+c_2\sqrt{x}\:J_{-1/4}\left(\frac{1}{2}x^2\right)$$
The derivative $f'(x)$ can be expressed in terms of Bessel functions in order to obtain the analytical result $y(x)=-\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$